# Check if random numbers in array contains 5 of them in ascending order

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hello I want to check if 5 random numbers in array are ascending.
Example from this:

```
var array = [2, 5, 5, 4, 7, 3, 6];
```

to this:

```
array = [2,3,4,5,6];
```

and of course if higher sequence is possible:

```
array = [3,4,5,6,7];
```

Is there any shortcut for this kind of sorting in jQuery?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: jQuery is not a catch-all for everything. Also, sit down and think about it. Assuming you know how to use `for` loops, how would you verify that each number is greater than the last? Don't even think about code yet. Just work it out in pseudo-code then write the JS to match.

Comment: are you checking or converting?

Comment: @Redu just checking but need to know the highest value in sorted array.
I am writing poker texas holdem in js. Got array with numbers of cards from table and one of players. I would like to check if there is straight aka 5 consecutive numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var array = [2, 5, 5, 4, 7, 3, 6];
//first convert into an object literal for fast lookups.
var ao = {};
array.forEach(function (e) { ao[e] = true; });

//now loop all in array, and then loop again for 5
array.forEach(function (num) {
  var count = 0, l;
  for (l = 0; l < 5; l ++) {
    if (ao[num + l]) count ++;
  }
  if (count === 5) {
    //found, push into array just to show nice in console
    var nums = [];
    for (l = 0; l < 5; l ++) {
      nums.push(num + l);
    }
    console.log(nums.join(','));
  }
});
```

Comment: That is what i was looking for! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this will do the trick:

- get unique members
- sort them
- slice last 5

(or reverse, slice first 5, reverse) like I did, since your array could be less then 5.

If resulting array has length of 5 then you have a positive answer.

```
console.log($.unique([2,5,5,4,7,3,6]).sort().reverse().slice(0,5).reverse())
```

Answer (score 0):

You might do as follows;

```js
function checkStraight(a){
  var s = [...new Set(a)].sort((a,b) => a-b);
  return s.length >= 5 && s.reduce((p,c,i,a) => c - a[i-1] === 1 ? ++p
                                                                 : p < 5 ? 1
                                                                         : p , 1) > 4;
}
var array = [2, 5, 5, 4, 7, 3, 6, 9],
   result = checkStraight(array);
console.log(result);
```